# Regular expression literal

Tags: regex

As I'm RegEx dyslexic..  what RegEx can you use to find each of the following strings - with the exception of "LoginException"?

```
NullPointerException
LoginException
BooException
Abc123Exception
```

**Edit:** To be clear, I'm looking for these strings in a text/log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when you want a regular expression that matches anything except a particular string or pattern, it's almost always more straightforward to invert the sense of the test. So instead of “here’s a pattern I hope matches anything except *XYZ*,” check whether XYZ matches and throw away the positives.

If you want only those three, use

```
$ egrep '(NullPointer|Boo|Abc123)Exception' input.log
```

You could probably get away with a two-stage pipeline, *e.g.*,

```
$ grep Exception input.log | grep -v LoginException
```

Comment: Fair enough but there are n number of exceptions I want to know about and only 1 I don't want to know about.  And I can't list all the possible positives.

Comment: @Marcus So why doesn't throwing away the ones you don't care about using `grep -v LoginException` as in the latter example do the trick?

Comment: Yup, using the 'two-stage pipeline' approach..  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming PCRE (Perl-Compatible RegEx)-like syntax (i.e. `grep -P`):

```
\b(?!LoginException\b)\w*Exception\b
```

Example:

```
echo "NullPointerException LoginException BooException Abc123Exception LoginFooException" |
grep -P '\b(?!LoginException\b)\w*Exception\b'
```

Comment: Similarly to @Mark, I got `bash: !LoginException$: event not found`.  And didn't work in Textpad.  Do they use a different RegEx syntax?

Comment: Not sure `^` and `$` are correct here - @Marcus wanted to "find" these strings (so I suppose he means "within a larger body of text"), not match a regex against them. Perhaps he should clarify his question...

Comment: Hmm.. I get: grep: illegal option -- P / Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?!Login)\b\w+Exception
```

You can do it for example with Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print if /(?!Login)\b\w+Exception/' < mylog.log
```

Comment: I added a `\b` or this regex would happily match "oginException" after having skipped the "L".

Comment: Tried this in bash, got `bash: !Login: event not found`.   Also didn't work in Textpad..

Comment: `grep (?!Login)\b\w+Exception mylog.log`.  And then using the Textpad GUI.